# Dynamically changing Icons of tabs in Java JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtabbedpane

UPDATED***
How do I dynamically change an icon of a tab in JTabbedPane?
This is the code. I need the icon to change from initial-processing-final
This code is just going initial-final

Code:

```
package tabs;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class ChangeIconTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ChangeIconTest window = new ChangeIconTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ChangeIconTest() {
        initialize();
        addtabs();

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 262);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);


    }

    private void addtabs(){
        tabbedPane.insertTab("tab name", displayInitial(), addButton(), null, 0);
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);

    }

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = ChangeIconTest.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Icon displayInitial(){
        ImageIcon initialIcon = createImageIcon("first.gif");
        return initialIcon;
    }
    public Icon displayMid(){


        ImageIcon midIcon = createImageIcon("second.gif");
        return midIcon;

    }
    public Icon displayFinal(){

        ImageIcon finalIcon2 = createImageIcon("third.jpg");
        return finalIcon2;
    }


    public Component addButton(){
        JButton jb = new JButton("The Big Button to change the Icon");
        jb.addActionListener(new ChangeTabListener());
        return jb;
    }

    class ChangeTabListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tabbedPane.setIconAt(0, displayMid());
            tabbedPane.revalidate();
            tabbedPane.repaint();
            tabbedPane.setIconAt(0, displayFinal());
            tabbedPane.revalidate();
            tabbedPane.repaint();
        }



    }
}
```

So what should I add or modify? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using Thread.sleep()? You are probably causing the Event Dispatch Thread to sleep which means the GUI can't repaint itself.

If you want to dynamically change the Icon for a certain period of time then use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the changing of the icon.

If you need more help then update your question and post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thread.sleep is working because it changed to the final Icon. Posted a runnable code just now

Comment: @PhilipMorris `Thread.sleep is working because it changed to the final Icon.` No it is not working. Yes the Thread will sleep for 2 seconds and do nothing. Then you attempt to change to a temporary icon and then a final icon, but the code executes too fast so you only ever see the final icon. Even if you add a Thread.sleep() between setting the temp icon and the final icon you will not see the temp icon because the GUI will sleep before it can repaint the icon. Then when it wakes up it will paint the final icon right away. I've given you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this

```
tabs.revalidate();
tabs.repaint();
```

Or

```
tabs.getParent().revalidate();
tabs.getParent().repaint();
```